# HTML5 / JavaScript Game - Editing JS code to change AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am working on a small game daily game for a client which will be implemented into their website.

The company decided we would use HTML5 + JavaScript.

The game requires a user of a database as we need to request JSON models about the users. Now my only fear is that, I know JavaScript can be changed through debugging tools, so could someone change what's pasted in to the AJAX request?

We're building a spin the wheel game, say in the code we have a random number which is the chance of them getting the jack pot prize, would they be able to edit the code to change the random number to 1 and always spin and win the jack pot prize?

Just really wonder is using HTML5 / JavaScript + AJAX safe? Is there anything I need to take into account when doing this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you could prevent the js from being changed on your specific page, anybody could write their own script that queries the server. For this application, the random generator should be implemented on the server side and returned to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side code, due to reasons you yourself mentioned (accessability and editability) is inherently unsafe. You can't keep a malicious user from requesting data that should not be visible to them, you need to control the access to the data on the backend - ie. even if they manage to send an "illegal" request, they should not be served with the corresponding data.

With regard to your spin-the-wheel game, you'd have to move your chance based logic to the backend, which you query in an ajax call from the frontend to determine whether a jackpot was hit or not.